# Why is importlib not able to import a module two levels up

Tags: python-import, python-importlib

I am trying  to import a module with importlib but I am get ***No module named 'configuration'***
This is my directory 
I am trying to run app.py which loads configuration two levels up

I tried using

```
importlib.import_module( 'configuration' )
configuration_module = importlib.import_module( '.config_loader', package='configuration' )
```

it's not able to load configuration

--home
    ---configuration 
             ---config.py 
              --- **init**.py
    ---restful 
              --- **init**.py 
               ---application 
                                   --- app.py
                    --- config.py 
                    --- __init__py

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "application/app.py", line 214, in <module>
    app = create_app()
  File "application/app.py", line 39, in create_app
    importlib.import_module( 'configuration' )
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 965, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'configuration'
```